# how to save registred users in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

here is my form.py file.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class register_form(UserCreationForm):
   first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
   last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
   class Meta():
      model = User
      fields = ('username','email')
```

here's my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
    bio = models.TextField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    joined_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.user.username
```

here's views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import register_form
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import profile
# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == "post":
        register = register_form(request.post)
        if register.is_valid():
            register.save()
            newUser=User(username=request.POST['username'],
                         email=request.POST['email'],
                         password=request.POST['password'])
            newUser.save()
            new_profile = profile(user=newUser,
                          first_name=request.POST["first_name"],
                          last_name=request.POST["last_name"])
            new_profile.save()
            return render(request,'users/success.html')
    else:
        register = register_form()
    return render(request,'users/register.html',{"register":register})
```

here's the urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/',views.register,name="register"),
]
```

and here's the register.html file:

```html
{% extends 'users/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<title>register</title>
{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>instagram clone</h1>
        <p>register to view     images and videos fo your friends</p>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{register|crispy}}
            <input type="submit" value="register">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

the django version used in is django 3.1 and python version is:3.8,
the problem is when I click on submit button it is named register, the function isn't rendering for me success.html page, and another thing is that the registred users aren't found in the database.

and here's the git repository for this project that I'm working on [all source code repository](https://github.com/amardahm/instaClone)

Comment: remove line: register.save()

Comment: if register.is_valid(): you don't have else statement

Comment: what about this line of code profile.objects.create(user=instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"POST"` and `"post"` are not equal, and Django returns the former for `request.method`

**views.py**

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ....
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method

Answer (score 0):

yes the problem is with post that I wrote in lower charachters, it has to be changed to upper case characters, the lines should be written like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    register = register_form(request.POST)
    ......
```

and when getting password from the input I need to write request.POST["password1"] instead of password, because i the HTML document it's name was password1,

```
newUser=User(username=request.POST['username'],
                     email=request.POST['email'],
                     password=request.POST['password1'])
```

and when going to the html document I need to change the method post to this:

```html
<form method="POST">
....
```